# Pandas column that references itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

> ```
>             Open   High    Low  Close     
> Date                                                                            
> 2014-03-31  10.61  10.61  10.61  10.61        
> 2014-04-01  10.66  10.66  10.66  10.66         
> 2014-04-02  10.67  10.67  10.67  10.67        
> 2014-04-03  10.64  10.64  10.64  10.64        
> 2014-04-04  10.57  10.57  10.57  10.57     
> 2014-04-07  10.50  10.50  10.50  10.50      
> 2014-04-08  10.51  10.51  10.51  10.51
> ```

I want to add a column `df['Ave']` that multiplies some constant or function by `df['Ave'].shift(1)`. What is the most elegant way to do this?

When I try to do it I get a KeyError. I also considered setting `df['Ave'].head(1) = df['Close']` and then starting the function from the second row of the dataframe, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any column with name 'Ave' in your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": range(1,5)})
df
```

output:

```
    col
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

To update column such that row[0] has 2 * row[1] value we use the following code.

```
df['col'] = 2 * df['col'].shift(-1)
df
```

output:

```
col
0   4.0
1   6.0
2   8.0
3   NaN
```

you can also do `df['col'] = 2 * df['col'].shift(1)` for replacing row[1] data with 2 * row[0] value and so on.

Answer (score 1):

so your avg is just this:

```
avg = df.mean(axis=1)
```

if you want some sort of constant, it's easy:

```
df['Avg'] =  avg.shift(1) * constant
```

if you need a function, you might have to do something like:

```
df['Avg'] = avg.shift(1).apply(f)
```

and then you can just set the first row manually:

```
df.Avg.iloc[0] = df.Close.iloc[0]
```